# Should I re-validate form inputs in php that are already validated in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I understand that javascript validations only serve a purpose for the client side and to keep vulnerabilities out of the server side and I need to validate the security of the inputs in php.

I have already validated what types of inputs a user can input in the form from the client side (using javascript) like the following example:

```
if(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i.test(document.getElementById(idName).value)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

And I have already tested done the following tests on the form inputs in php:

```
$fname = $lname = $saddress = $city = $state = $zip = $email = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    $saddress = test_input($_POST["saddress"]);
    $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
    $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
    $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Do I need to also re-validate using regex what type of inputs a user is able to input in the form AGAIN in the php? Or using htmlentities is sufficient on the server side while using regex validations on the client side?

Any information is much appreciated!

Thanks, Al

Comment: yes the user can change the behavior of you js or disable js

Comment: @madalinivascu they can change the behavior of my js only on their end and not for everyone else correct? Then I would assume that this user is a malicious one and shouldn't I at this point only worry about using the htmlentities to keep my site from having vulnerabilities?

Comment: consider if user disables javascript on the browser your input will be send unvalidated

Comment: @madalinivascu Ok thank you, It seems that I will be validating on server side as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always validate everything in the server side. Since everybody can change your javascript client code through the browser using tools like Findbugs, or Chrome tools, it isn't secure to validate only in Javascript.

What you validates at the client side is only to give a better experience to the user.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to be considering is fall back - what if the user turns off JavaScript? I have had occasions where I have provided a neat piece of Jquery to resolve an issue - only for it to not function for intermittent clients.

You should always sanitize form inputs coming in on the server side. 
Otherwise you could easily leave yourself open to vulnerabilities.

PHP's filter functions can help you with filtering / sanitizing input:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

As for regex - consider if you need to on the server side, it has a high overhead that you might not need - as long as you are sanitizing the input and handling all possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should always validate inputs on the server side regardless of what validations you have on the client side. The user can technically send anything to your server and do some SQL injections or otherwise send bad or unallowed data.

Use javascript only to help the user fill in the right things (like, immediately notifying them if they have entered an invalid email address).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must done server side validations. you cannot trust JavaScript validations. Because javascript is run within the browser. So user will get control over it. Also javascript can be disabled on browsers. In such cases it will skip validations. A simple example i have seen many people use something like this

```
 <form  name='frm' onSubmit='return validate();'>
```

With an inspection tool it is possible to change this to

```
<form name='frm'>
```

Then it will skip the client side validations.

It will take bit more time for (client + server) validations. but still when you consider security it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, the user can easily bypass the JS validation and post directly to the server, having said that, validade the form only on the server side, it will save you some code but at the same time you'll need to spare more server resources.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you use server side validation to validate input also.
Please tell me which field you want to validate on server.

Comment: I already have validations for them in javascript so it wouldn't be too difficult to use the same regex to create validations in my php. The fields I want to validate are the above and then some.